# Is it possible to know the Tomcat version having the URL?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, server, tomcat7

I am new to server-side programming,

Is it possible to know the Tomcat version having the website URL?

I know that it is using Tomcat because of logo showed when seeing it in a browser.

Thanks

Comment: If correctly administered, suppose no. Simple "demo" installation can have few admin webapps at default URL-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to detect the version of Tomcat just given the website's URL.

If you were to fetch a resource in that web application and cause Tomcat to throw an error, and the server is configured such, you can see the version number in the error message page.

Generally speaking, it's considered a security problem to advertize the exact version of server software because vulnerabilities for a certain version are very likely to work if attempted against that server. If you don't tell the client what version you are, they are forced to *try* a particular attack, and then you can perhaps detect the attack itself.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat, when have 404 problem (page not exist) - and error-page isn't changed, then original silver-blue, show version

HTTP Status 404 - /IntranetV5a/listamodulow

type Status report

message /IntranetV5a/listamodulow

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.54

Then to some degree have chance to see version of server

PRACTICAL: if Yoy have wrong URL, can provoke server to displaying such message